# A specific way to truncate all other peaks in an array

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following figure from a 1D numpy array.

[image]

I simply want to eliminate all the other subpeaks, that is, all local maxes except the *global max* and floor them to the mean (or mode) of the density of points in the bottom layer. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: For starters, you could tell us what sort of data structure you have backing this graph, and maybe show us your code?

Comment: How do you define a peak: as any point with a local maximum, as any point that is more than a threshold above its neighbours, ...?

Comment: @NickBailey, the code is superfluous in this context. I'm using a fitter to fit to the correlation length of spins in the Ising model. I'm just wondering what tools I can use to send all local peaks other than the maximum peak to some value corresponding to the mode of the data.

Comment: @BasSwinckels, any point with a local maximum.

Comment: What if a subpeak consists of two samples with the same value? Those points are not local maxima. The hard part is the peak finding, this will depend on how noisy your data is etc. Once you have found them, setting all except the highest one to some median value is a piece of cake. What did you try to find all peaks?

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
local_maxes = np.where(np.r_[True, x[1:] > x[:-1]] & np.r_[x[:-1] > x[1:], True])[0]
global_max  = local_maxes[np.argmax(x[local_maxes])]

for i in local_maxes:
    if i == global_max: continue
    # Do something with x[i]
```

`local_maxes` is a list of indices *i* where *i* is greater than the two elements on either side of it (boundaries only check interior element).

`global_max` is the index *i* where *x*[*i*] is greatest.